# Regular Expression this or this

Tags: php, regex

Example:

```
preg_match_all('/example\.com\/lamp\/(\w+)/i', $string, $matches);
```

What I want:

- It should look for "lamp" but also for let's say for "car".
- It should contain "lamp" OR "car"

I know this is simple and I should have use google. 
But I did not know what I should google.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: car? where? can you give some urls and what you expect your regular expression to return.

Comment: @FelixKling - Cool, I didn't know that shortcut.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/example\.com\/(lamp|car|anything|you|want)\/(\w+)/i', $string, $matches);
```

You can use the `|` sign to match one of many possible strings.

Answer (score 2):

In regular expression you can use a pipe (|) as a logical OR operator

read this:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/72regular/

Answer (score 1):

You could also match anything at all. This: `[^\/]+` will match "one or more of anything except `/`"

```
preg_match_all('/example\.com\/[^\/]+\/(\w+)/i', $string, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

That would look for example.com/lamp/ + one or more "word" characters.

If you want just to make not fixed the "lamp" part, it hould be:

```
preg_match_all('/example\.com\/(\w+)\/(\w+)/i', $string, $matches);
```